# Задача для новичка. Вывести объект из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо:
Существует список. Вывести объект из списка при вводе его индекса (input). Если в списке 5 человек, а вводят цифру 6, программа должна сказать «всего в списке 5 человек. Введите номер от 0 – 4». Если вводится буква, программа говорит: «Введите цифру!». И так по кругу.

```
b = ['Маша', 'Ваня', 'Лена', 'Марина', 'Арнольд']
c = len(b)
dd = c - 1
while True:
    def x():
        while True:
            try:
                x = int(input('Введите номер учатника: '))
                if x > c:
                    print('В списке всего ' + c + ' человек. Введите номер от 0 до ' + dd +'!')
                else:
                    return x
            except ValueError:
                print('Введите число!')
    print(b[x])
```

Выдает ошибку. Но, в силу неопытности, не могу понять что именно не так.

Comment: Вы объявили функцию, но нигде её не вызвали, попробуйте `print(x())` но это не единственная ваша проблема

Comment: Да, я еще исправил тут:
print('В списке всего ' + str(c) + ' человек. Введите номер от 0 до ' + str(dd) +'!')

Если делать print(x()), выводит не то. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что значит я нигде ее не вызвал. Я пытаюсь ее вызвать в print.

Comment: Ещё в `if` вы не учли, что числа бывают отрицательные

Comment: Если вы про эту строку `print(b[x])`, то тут вы вызываете функцию print с аргументов b[x]. b у вас определено в первой строке, а переменная x определяется в функции x. Чтобы определить переменную x, вам надо вызвать функцию x(). Я этого не вижу. Чтобы стало понятнее, используйте разные имена для функции x и переменной x. print(b[x()]), конечно) перепутала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

break останавливает(ломает) цикл и идёт дальше по ходу вывод человека лучше перенести в блок `else` так как так будет понятнее, ибо если `x` входит в диапазон длины `b` то мы выводим имя человека

```
b = ['Маша', 'Ваня', 'Лена', 'Марина', 'Арнольд']
c = len(b) 
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('Введите номер учатника: '))
        if x > c:
            print('В списке всего ' + str(c-1) + ' человек. Введите номер от 0 до ' + str(c) +'!')
        else:
            print(b[x-1])
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Введите число!')
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!